# Bootstrap3 - Site does not scroll to revealed content via tabs or accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a site using Bootstrap 3 with a few modifications (added the full-width video header from Bootsnip, utilizing animated.css). I am trying to limit the user's ability to navigate through the page, making them click to reveal content sections. I used the existing Bootstrap Javascript for tabbed navigation and for collapsing content to facilitate the hide/reveal. This all works; however, in IE11 the scroll is not working correctly. Links are formatted as such`<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#donation" data-toggle="tab">` and the targets are formatted as `<div class="tab-pane fade" id="donation">`

In Firefox, it works about 50% of the time - the other half of the time the buttons will reveal the content, but the browser doesn't "follow" it down (if that makes sense).

I have tried using scrolling-nav.js (adopted from http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/) to accomplish this (and adding page-scroll as a class to all links, but the scroll behavior doesn't kick in unless I click a link twice (once to uncollapse, second to navigate) so that's not a desirable outcome.

I have also tried swapping out the href tags for data-target tags, but that didn't seem to make a difference. I've tried changing orders of classes and layouts - no difference.

URL: http://aiacorporation.com/marketing/fullvideo/

EDIT 9/10 for clarity - As a note, I am not specifically looking for the smooth-scrolling type experience. Just for the browser to actually follow the navigation and navigate TO the content as it is being revealed (as the reveals all have their own animation anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Bootstrap documentation it looks like firing the events via JS and then tying in .scrollTop after the event has fired would solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `data-toggle="collapse"` and it should work properly

```
<a href="#gift" class="btn btn-info animated btn1 fadeInUp">Get Your Gift</a>
```

If you want it to work as in the `scrolling-nav` demo, then I would go back and review all of the changes that you made to their template to find the one that's causing the issue.

Comment: The collapse is intentional. I want the content of the site to be hidden until after the message is displayed. I suppose I could just add a delayed fade-in until after the message would be displayed if I can't have both scrolling + collapsing.

Comment: I am working with Chrome - when I remove `data-toggle="collapse"` the new content displays after I click and the window moves to the `#gift` location.

Comment: Tried it, and on Firefox and IE11 the content (target) stays collapsed. I could remove the collapse class on the target but that defeats the purpose. I started with the stock Bootstrap framework, added the video bootsnip (adds initializing YTPlayer to bootstrap.js), added animated.css (which makes no changes to the core), and then after I couldn't make both the scroll and collapse work I tried scrolling-nav.js as a possible solution. It does not need to be part of the solution as the JS/CSS behind the collapse and fade include transitions and scrolling actions - they're just not firing.